# No Shop provided message showing while run project in Shopify

Tags: node.js, express, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I am working on "Shopify",And Right now i am trying to run project but i am getting error
"No Shop provided"
How can i remove this error ? How can my project/api work ? Here is image of my shopify app.
[image]

Comment: "How can i remove this error ?" - Providing a shop will probably remove the error.

Comment: @Geshode How can i do this ? i am new in shopify so kindly guide

Comment: Maybe [this](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/quot-no-shop-provided-quot/td-p/1999047) will help.

Comment: @Geshode already tried but not worked for me , what is wrong with app (screenshot posted) ? Is this fine (status of app)  ?

Comment: Can you update the question with more details? This question is very generic.